# Failed to fetch ros-cturtle-web-interface for lucid: "404 not found"

Tags: ros, ubuntu, pr2, cturtle, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm setting up a build server and trying to match as best I can the packages on the three latest versions: cturtle, diamondback, electric.

In trying to install `ros-cturtle-pr2`, apt attempts to get `ros-cturtle-web-interface`:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  ros-cturtle-web-interface
```

And I'm getting a `404` on `apt-get install` attempt:

```
Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-cturtle-web-interface/ros-cturtle-web-interface_0.4.4-s1302754950~lucid_i386.deb  404  Not Found
```

It looks like the apt package list is listing a package it doesn't have.

I'm in the process of submitting a bug report, but wanted to ask here first before I submit. Anyone familiar with this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10922/failed-to-fetch-ros-cturtle-web-interface-for-lucid:-%22404-not-found%22/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-08-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The cturtle Debian packages have been updated. You need to run "sudo apt-get update" to get the latest package index. After that, installing should just work fine. You can check on the server http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-cturtle-web-interface/ what the current build version of the package is.

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My guess would be that packages.ros.org's state has become inconsistent. That file is available from at least the CWRU ROS mirror, so it had to be on packages.ros.org sometime in the past few weeks.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-08-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-08-16**:
Thanks. I didn't think to check the mirror. Bug submitted #5124: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5124